# Gatsby Remark plugin: Created nodes visible to GraphIQL but queries on Gatsby pages return null

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm working on a plugin for gatsby-transformer-remark. In my plugin, I take data from the Remark transformer and create a graphql node of a new type. When I start the site and open GraphIQL at http://localhost:8000/___graphql, I can see my plugin's new node and its data. However, when I try to access that node's data in a Gatsby page component, the graphql query returns null for that node type. Why does the data not appear in the graphql query on my page? Can I not create new graphql nodes in Remark plugins? The Remark gatsby plugin API provides the necessary methods for creating nodes.

I have a minimal reproduction repo at this link. Instructions for running it and seeing the issue are in the readme.

https://github.com/timothymcmackin/test-create-nodes

I create the graphQL node in `plugins/gatsby-remark-internal-toc/index.js` by using the `createNode` method:

```js
  if (headings.length > 0) {
    const { createNode } = actions;

    const headingNode = {
      headings: headings,
      path: markdownNode.frontmatter.path,
      id: createNodeId(`${markdownNode.frontmatter.path}.${markdownNode.frontmatter.title}`),
      children: [],
      internal: {
        description: `Headings and links for ${markdownNode.fileAbsolutePath}`,
        type: "topicInternalHeadings",
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(headings),
        content: JSON.stringify(headings),
      }
    };

    await createNode(headingNode);
  }
```

I start the site with the Gatsby `develop` command. Then I open graphIQL and run this query:

```
query MyQuery {
  topicInternalHeadings(path: {eq: "/mypage.html"}) {
    headings {
      level
      path
      text
    }
  }
}
```

The query returns data for the `topicInternalHeadings` node.

Then I open `http://localhost:8000/myPage.html` which has a similar query on it. However, the results of its query are:

```
{markdownRemark: {…}, topicInternalHeadings: null}
```

#### Expected result

The graphql node data that I create in the plugin is available to both graphiql and graphql queries on Gatsby pages.

#### Actual result

The node data is available to graphiql but graphql queries on Gatsby pages return null.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together a reproduction repo! Unfortunately I can't reproduce, `topicInternalQuery` is also `null` in GraphiQL for me. It could be a cache issue, can you try `gatsby clean` and let me know if this solves it?

Comment: Strange -- I ran `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby develop` and I see the data in GraphiQL. Not sure what could be happening that we see different results. Different versions of Gatsby? I've updated to gatsby to 2.19.12 and gatsby-transformer-remark 2.6.50. I committed my yarn.lock file, so maybe try using that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that the query in my page had no name, so instead of this:

```
 query {
   allMdx(sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}, limit: 6) {
  edges {
.....
```

Do this:

```
query SomeMeaningFulName {
   allMdx(sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}, limit: 6) {
  edges {
```